# Is it safe to use `pointer::add` if the boundary check is delayed?

Tags: rust

The final goal is to remove the panic condition in the compiled code (`test` function).

Sample code:

```rust
pub fn test(bytes: &[u8]) -> Option<u8> {
    let mut viewer = Viewer::new(bytes);
    if let Some(b'0') = viewer.try_peek() {
        viewer.skip(1);
    }

    viewer.try_peek()
}

pub struct Viewer<'a> {
    ptr: *const u8,
    end: *const u8,
    marker: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a [u8]>,
}

impl<'a> Viewer<'a> {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new(bytes: &'a [u8]) -> Self {
        let ptr = bytes.as_ptr();
        let end = unsafe { ptr.add(bytes.len()) };

        // if ptr > end {
        //     unsafe { ::std::hint::unreachable_unchecked() };
        // }

        Self {
            ptr,
            end,
            marker: std::marker::PhantomData,
        }
    }

    #[inline]
    pub fn try_peek(&self) -> Option<u8> {
        if self.ptr == self.end {
            // or >=
            return None;
        }

        Some(unsafe { *self.ptr })
    }

    #[inline]
    pub fn skip(&mut self, n: usize) {
        //let new_ptr = unsafe { self.ptr.add(n) };
        let new_ptr = self.ptr.wrapping_add(n);

        if new_ptr > self.end {
            panic!("out of bounds")
        }

        self.ptr = new_ptr;
    }
}
```

From the documentation of [`pointer::add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.add) I should use [`pointer::wrapping_add`][`wrapping_add`] because I don't know the value of `n`, but it pessimizes optimization:

> Both the starting and resulting pointer must be either in bounds or one byte past the end of the same [allocated object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/index.html#allocated-object).

The second problem I don't understand is why I have to use `unreachable_unchecked` or `>=` (see the comments in the code), but from the documentation of `add`:

> The computed offset, in bytes, cannot overflow an isize.

As a result, if I use `add` instead of `wrapping_add` and uncomment `unreachable_unchecked`, I will get a normally working combination of `try_peek() + skip(1)`, but also Undefined Behavior.

- Rust version: `1.72`
- Compiler flags: `-C opt-level=3`

Comment: Instead of messing with unsafe code, why won't you just use a simple slice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you must use `wrapping_add()`. `add()` will be Undefined Behavior. As soon as the result of `add()` exceeds the allocated object, it is immediate undefined behavior, *even if the resulting pointer is never used*.

Yes, that blocks optimizations, but those optimizations are incompatible with your code. Therefore, you *should* block them. Also, they will 99.99% not matter for you. In extreme cases, they will award you one instruction or two, and therefore at most one cycle. Unless your code is *extremely* performance-sensitive, you won't even notice the difference.

Unfortunately, even with `wrapping_add()`, you can never remove the check even if you use `>=` for `try_peek()`. That's because with enough `skip()`s you can wrap around the address space. Then your pointer will be invalid, even though it will be less than `self.end`.

Also, you can avoid the `add()` in `new()` by using [`<[T]>::as_ptr_range()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.as_ptr_range).

As a last note, the `unreachable_unchecked()` in `new()` does nothing. If the `add()` in `new()` could make the pointer invalid, `unreachable_unchecked()` would not be the solution: it would just make the problem worse by making it immediate UB and more chance for things to mess up (although perhaps this is a good thing). Since it cannot, and will always produce a valid pointer, this is just useless. Perhaps it can be used to inform the optimizer, but I bet it already knows enough from the `add()`.

Comment: thanks for answer. About `the unreachable_unchecked() in new() does nothing` - is work same as `>=`. (enable optimization if I use `add`.

Comment: @qRoC Do you have a code showing it optimizes better? Because I tend to think it won't, and perhaps even worse.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/jxKd4EWo5 work same as `>=`

Comment: `are incompatible with your code` - why? the main reason - is to remove hundreds of extra panics that will never be executed

Comment: @qRoC I explained why, because it might wrap over.

Comment: @qRoC I don't understand what the godbolt is supposed to show.